# Apply same format on multiple string variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding a menu. Options 1,2 and 3 will populate `project`. Options 4, 5 and 6 depend on the value of `project`. I want to strikethrough options 4,5 and 6 if `project == None`.

```
project = None
menuOptions = {0 : 'Option4', 1 : 'Option5', 2 : 'Option6'}

print("""
Choose:

━━━━━━━━━━━━ Text ━━━━━━━━━━━━
1 : Option1 
2 : Option2
3 : Option3

━━━━━━━━━━━━ Text ━━━━━━━━━━━━
4 : {0}

━━━━━━━━━━━━ Text ━━━━━━━━━━━━
5 : {1}

━━━━━━━━━━━━ Text ━━━━━━━━━━━━
6 : {2}     

    
0 : Exit""".format('\u0336'.join(menuOptions[0]) + '\u0336' if project == None else menuOptions[0],
                   '\u0336'.join(menuOptions[1]) + '\u0336' if project == None else menuOptions[1],
                   '\u0336'.join(menuOptions[2]) + '\u0336' if project == None else menuOptions[2]))
```

The code above works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a way of reducing the necessary code following this idea:

```
format( 
    for opt in menuOptions: 
        '\u0336'.join(menuOptions[opt]) + '\u0336' if project == None else menuOptions[opt]
)
```

The objective is to be able to add new elements into menuOptions, show them in the menu and apply the same formatting without having to "hardcode" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a starred comprehension here:

```
"""...""".format(*('\u0336'.join(opt) + '\u0336' if project is None else opt
                   for opt in menuOptions))
```

Comment: Works just as intended, just had to change the `.join(opt)` with `.join(menuOptions[opt])` . Thanks, I didn't know about argument unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

So not sure if this is what you wanted, but you can reduce the "hardcording" a bit by doing this:

```
# list comprehension to get format options 
# (you can use a loop here instead for more readability if needed)
x = ['\u0336'.join(menuOptions[opt]) + '\u0336' if project == None else menuOptions[opt] for opt in menuOptions]

print("""
Choose:

━━━━━━━━━━━━ Text ━━━━━━━━━━━━
1 : Option1 
2 : Option2
3 : Option3

━━━━━━━━━━━━ Text ━━━━━━━━━━━━
4 : {0}

━━━━━━━━━━━━ Text ━━━━━━━━━━━━
5 : {1}

━━━━━━━━━━━━ Text ━━━━━━━━━━━━
6 : {2} 

    
0 : Exit""".format(*x))
```

The `*` operator unpacks the list for you.